# How to use not thread safe 3rdParty dependencies in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

How "thread safe" is Spark? I have something like this, in java:

```
class A implements Function<String, Boolean> {
    NotThreadSafe3rdParty calculator = new NotThreadSafe3rdParty();
    public Boolean call(String s) {
        return calculator.calc(s);
    }
}

class B implements Function<String, Boolean> {
    static NotThreadSafe3rdParty calculator;
    static {
        calculator = new NotThreadSafe3rdParty();
    }
    public Boolean call(String s) {
        return calculator.calc(s);
    }
}

class MyRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myPath = "/data/path";
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> myData = sc.textFile(myPath);

        long numAs = myData.filter(new A()).count();
        long numBs = myData.filter(new B()).count();
    }
}
```

1. Is the use of class A correct?
2. Is the use of class B correct?
3. What if class A NotThreadSafe3rdParty is a jni wrapper over c code (e.g. crfsuite ?)
4. How to use such dependencies correctly?

Comment: Did you find any more resources on your questions in the meantime? I would also like to see answers to these.